# MySQL Workbench Unable to Connect to Remotely-Hosted Database, with error re Localhost

Tags: mysql-workbench

MySQL Workbench with a fresh install on a new Windows 10 laptop where this software has not been installed before, using mysql-workbench-community-8.0.29-winx64.msi and accepted all default values in the wizard.

I've created a new MySQL database for a knowledge base hosted on a WordPress website.

- WordPress and DB Hosted At: Name.com
- WordPress and DB Hosted On: same
  server
- Server IP: 169.62.56.10
- Server Apache Version: 2.4.53
- Server PHP Version: 7.4.29
- Server Architecture: x86_64
- Server Operating System: linux
- DB Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- DB Server type: MySQL
- DB Server version: 8.0.29 - MySQL Community Server - GPL
- DB Port: 3306
- DB Schema: becca37_ps_kb
- DB User: becca37_ps_kb_admin, with associated password
- Remote MySQL: I added % as an allowed host (I would, of course, like to crank this down later but first need the connection(s) working at all :0) )

---

And am now trying to connect to it.

(1) via WordPress for wpDataTables plugin use, as a separate connection than the WordPress config uses since this is using a separate database schema than the WordPess tables. This method is working flawlessly. Yay!

---

These other two are not working.

I'm SURE it's something I did or didn't do. Almost always is. :0)

I've tried turning off windows firewall, no change.

What are the other things I need to check from my environment end? Configuration? Etc.?

Note: I have no other control over the hosting server or remote database itself (e.g. no server-level config changes, etc., no database-level config or permission changes, etc., etc.)

---

(2) via MySQL Workbench from my laptop.

I do not have a local MySQL server running; my understanding is that I do not need that if I'm only wanting to connect to remotely hosted MySQL databases.

- Connection Method: Standard (TCP/IP)
- Hostname: as above
- Port: as above
- Username: as above
- Password: stored in vault
- Default schema: as above

Error Message:

"Your connection attempt failed for user 'becca37_ps_kb_admin' to the MySQL server at 169.62.56.10:3306: Unable to connect to localhost"

I've tried running MySQL Workbench "as administrator", no change.

---

(3) Via HeidiSQL based on some suggestions in others posts.

- Network type: MariaDB or MySQL (TCP/IP)
- Library: libmysql.dll (also tried with libmysql-6.1.dll, no change)
- Hostname / IP" as above
- User: as above
- Password: input
- Port: as above
- Databases: as above

Error Message:

"Can't connect to MySQL server on '169.62.56.10' (10060)"

Comment: The error 10060 is returned by the MySQL client when a connection could not be established with the service on the system you are connecting to. This is commonly caused by a firewall block or network issue preventing the connection.

Comment: Especially if you can't connect through all the methods .. it means that its not those programs but rather the connection.  Could be something in your control or something out, like maybe you are over seas and trying to connect to a USA location and a central station has some Juniper rules to block certain country regions .. not even remotely saying this is the issue, just sort of an example of something out of your hands that you wouldn't notice without doing tons of log gathering and path tracing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments @easleyfixed!

Apparently, I was unable to properly communicate my issue to the customer service reps I talked with at the host as they insist they do not allow remote access at all even though they enable that option for us to set on their control panel and they have multiple knowledge base articles on how to do it.

So, a new hosting service has been found and I've migrated everything.

Updated MySQL Workbench with the values from the new host and voila, no connection issues. :0)

Comment: I know you still can not upvote, however, please refrain from "saying thanks" unless its relevant.